# Frobenius norm overflow issue with my implementation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, computer-science

I implemented the following definition of a Forbenius norm in MATLAB
https://puu.sh/xXsJZ/c42a5e9eac.png

in the way that it is described (i.e. I did 2 for loops, and incremented a sum by squaring each of the elements, and at the end I took the square root of the sum).

My question is, is there a way to implement this norm so that if I input a fairly large number in the matrix, its square would not overflow? The function returns "Infinity" in some cases, even though the true Forbenius norm could be well under the machine's overflow threshold. (recall that a square root is taken at the end of the calculation).

edit: There's also the issue with underflow. Even if an element ai,j is not too small, its square may underflow. In MATLAB, an
element that underflows is set to 0. Now as long as some of the other elements are large
enough, the result still will be acceptable. If, on the other hand, all of the elements underflow, my function could incorrectly return 0.

Any help?

An example of a matrix that produces infinity on my machine is

[1, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999; 1, 1]

However, when I use the built-in Frobenius norm function, it works just fine with that input. Why might this be?

Comment: Please post an example that reproduces the problem. And consider vectorizing those loops if possible, you may get a large speed improvement

Comment: Matlab's [`norm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) already supports the Frobenius norm.

Comment: How does MATLAB implement the Frobenius norm? I looked at their definition and tried doing x = sqrt(trace(A* transpose(A))), however I still get the overflow issue. When I use the built-in Frobenius function (x = norm(A, 'fro')) I don't get the overflow issue.

Answer (score 1):

The following code, though in Java, is close to what Matlab is doing while calculating the Frobenius norm. The trick here is the `hypot` function which rather than just doing `x^2 + y^2`, it computes the hypotenuse avoiding under/over flow. `hypot` is available in matlab so instead of calculating `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`, use hypot and you should be able to avoid under/over flow.

```
public static double normFrob(double[][] matrix) {
    double norm = 0.0;
    int rows = matrix.length;
    int cols = matrix[0].length;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            norm = hypot(norm, matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return norm;
}

public static double hypot(double a, double b) {
    double r;
    if (Math.abs(a) > Math.abs(b)) {
        r = b / a;
        r = Math.abs(a) * Math.sqrt(1 + r * r);
    } else if (b != 0) {
        r = a / b;
        r = Math.abs(b) * Math.sqrt(1 + r * r);
    } else {
        r = 0.0;
    }
    return r;
}
```

This code snippet was taken from [Jama](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) which was an effort to introduce a Matrix library to Java and some of the developers are Matlab folks.

Comment: Matlab has a built-in `hypot` function as well.

Comment: @horchler good point. I was actually aiming for pseudo code but happen to have that java snippet handy. Since the OP didn't post any code it's hard to tell but my best bet is that `hypot` will fix his/her issue. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The overflow protection can be done in various ways. One possibility is normalization. This is Euclidean norm but the idea is the same

```
m_sum = 0;
y=max(abs(x));
for i=1:len(x)
  m_sum = m_sum + (x(i)/y)^2;
end
mynorm = y*sqrt(m_sum);
```